# Could not find or load main class Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I am new to JAVA. I am using Eclipse 3.7 with WindowBuilder Pro installed. I have made a JFrame SearchFrame.java using the GUI in the package SearchPackage.
[image]

But when I try to run this file it gives me the error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class SearchPackage.SearchFrame
```

I looked into my output folder DatabaseSearch/bin and there is no .class file in it. Please suggest me what should I do to rectify this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure that the auto build option is selected or manually compile the java by right click on the project and select build

Comment: @AlirezaFattahi I checked this, Build Automatically is already enabled.

Comment: As you said your classes are not made you must first force eclipse to build your classes. so the SearchFrame.class must be made in DatabaseSearch/bin

Comment: Right click your project and check your target path be valid may be the target path is not correct. I also suggest you build new workspace

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

Try to:

- Right click on the **Project** in **PackageExplorer** -> **Properties** -> **Java Build Path**
- Select **Order and Export** tab, and move the source package that contains the main class to the top, by selecting the correct package and pressing the **Up** button.

Answer (score 0):

Automatic builds may be disabled preventing the class file from being generated. Right click on

```
DatabaseSearch > Build Project
```

to use the manual build feature

Comment: Ok what happens when you clean & rebuild and re-run?

Answer (score 0):

Click right at project at Package Explorer the compile and run/

Answer (score 0):

Please clear all the build errors if any in your project. May be the project has some missing jars as a result its not able to form .class file out of your java.